# Potential issues when uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

Unfortunately my base environment has become corrupt and I need to uninstall and reinstall anaconda to fix the issue (not ideal!) I was reading the documentation:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

I am unable to "conda install anaconda-clean" because of the issue with my base environment which leaves me with Option A:

> "Open the Terminal.app or iTerm2 terminal application, and then remove
>   your entire Anaconda directory, which has a name such as anaconda2,
>   anaconda3, or ~/opt. Enter rm -rf ~/anaconda3 to remove the
>   directory."

-

> "This will leave a few files behind, which for most users is just
>   fine."

What I want to check is that these few files that are left behind, are these going to create any issues when I reinstall anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

The [`anaconda-clean` function](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-clean/blob/master/anaconda_clean.py) is basically a list of files to delete and an interactive for-loop. One can easily do the same thing manually.

Here is the list (which notably has not changed since 2016):

```
FILES = [
    '.anaconda', '.astropy', '.continuum',
    '.conda', '.condamanager', '.condarc',
    '.enthought', '.idlerc', '.glue', '.ipynb_checkpoints', '.ipython',
    '.jupyter', '.matplotlib', '.python-eggs',
    '.spyder2', '.spyder2-py3', '.theano',
]
```

As always, back stuff up first.

---

#### (Opinionated) Advice

Since you're starting fresh, I strongly encourage installing [Mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge) (a [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) variant that includes Mamba in the **base**) and *avoid installing anything but Conda infrastructure* in the **base** env. If you need Anaconda, simply create an env with it, e.g.,

```
conda create -n foo anaconda
```

Comment: So never run conda update all or conda update conda in base env? Thanks Merv, this is really useful. I think I'm going to uninstall and reinstall - are there any resources or do you have any other tips for best practices for managing conda envs?

Comment: @IainMacCormick `conda update conda` is definitely okay. The main issue comes when people start installing Python packages via `pip`. It's so easy to create new envs that it's just not worth the risk of frequently manipulating envs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure conda update conda is where I started with all these problems, although perhaps I had installed other packages on base a while ago (I'm sure I did a lot of stupid things when I was starting out.) Ok this is really helpful info!